# Should I ask a recruiter if they are still interested?

Tags: software-industry, recruitment

I was contacted on linkedIN by a recruiter at a big tech firm about a month ago saying how they are in the process of hiring new grads, and she asked for my updated resume. I sent her an email with my resume and a message of interest, she then replied that the hiring process is from August to December and that she'll be considering me for software developer/tester positions. If there would be a match her or one of her colleagues would email me.

About 2 weeks ago I realized that I made a small mistake in my resume (I put a comma instead of a period in my email) and sent her an email telling her that I'm sending her an updated resume because I wouldn't want one of her colleagues to email the wrong address. Her reply was Thanks for noticing that and sending the corrected resume.

So my question is should I try to be persistent and ask how the process is going? Since she didn't flat out say it probably wouldn't work. Also is it acceptable to politely ask if we're seriously being considered?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Well the first rule of dealing with recruiters is to assume you probably aren't seriously being considered.  Imagine if you were a recruiter.  How much of an incentive do you have to consider reqs that are apparently so complicated someone has to be hired to fill them.  No one knows what they want.  Every few days theres some post or other trending on LinkedIn about how absurd the hiring process is, and then everyone promptly goes out and does nothing to fix it.  I'd look at GPA, class rank, maybe years of experience... toss the rest.  Less work for everyone.

That's way more cynical than it needs to be, but do manage expectations.

With potential recruiters, unless I have a compelling reason to believe they've either written me off completely, or enjoying hearing from me, I use exponential back off starting with a weekly check-in.  That is, I send a message a week after the last contact of interest.  In the first e-mail, I'll ask if there's anything I can do to help the process, etc.  I'm sure you know what to say.

Then, I wait two weeks.  Write a shorter message.

Four weeks, even shorter.  Still communicate your interest and support.

And so on, it prevents people's inboxes from being spammed to exhausting, but still keeps you on the radar.

I've generally not had problems with this method, and once even managed to catch a snag in the hiring process that'd slipped through the cracks (shouldn't have been my responsibility, but remember, no one really seems to care that much) which helped land me a better position.  It's probably not perfect, but it's elegant, considerate, and has worked well for me.

Best of luck.